# List bullets: is it possible to use (1) an attribute for the content while (2) preserving text alignment?

Tags: html, css, layout

List bullets: is it possible to use (1) an attribute for the content while (2) preserving text alignment?

**Goal:**

```
       custom bullet text from attr : aligned list text
longer custom bullet text from attr : aligned list text
```

Attempt:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li data-bullet="custom bullet text from attr : "> aligned list text</li>
  <li data-bullet="longer custom bullet text from attr : "> aligned list text</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
list-style-type: attr(data-label);
```

**I can do (1) or (2), but not both:**

**I can get custom text without alignment**

```css
li::before {
  content: attr(data-bullet);
  margin-right: 5px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-bullet="glorp"> text to align</li>
  <li data-bullet="glorpulous">text to align</li>
</ul>
```

**Or aligned text, but only with a static list of predefined bullets**

```css
ol {
list-style-type: upper-roman;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>aligned text</li>
<li>aligned text</li>
<li>aligned text</li>
<li>aligned text</li>
<li>aligned text</li>
<li>aligned text</li>
<li>aligned text</li>
</ol>
```

**So, is there any way to have the bullet text come dynamically from an attribute in each individual `<li>` element, while keep the `<li>` text aligned?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use display:table and draw columns :

```css
li::before {
  content: attr(data-bullet)'.';
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
ul {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 5px 0;
}
li {
  display: table-row;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-bullet="glorp"> text to align</li>
  <li data-bullet="glorpulous">text to align</li>
</ul>
```

Else you will need to set a fixed width to the ::before .

Answer (score 2):

I did some messing around and found this out:

```css
ul{
  background:red;
}
li::before {
  content: attr(data-bullet);
  margin-right: 5px;
  background:green;
  display:block;
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  text-align:right;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background:blue;
  display:block;
  
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li data-bullet="glorp"> text to align</li>
  <li data-bullet="glorpulous">text to align</li>
</ul>
```

The styling is hideous and there is probably a better way to do it, but it seems to be working.

**EDIT:** And you have to predefine the width of the bullet part

Comment: Thanks.  I should have mentioned that the fixed-width was a dealbreaker, but nice demo!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time at the moment to mock it up, but I will try some version of using a flexbox set of two cols per row and `whitespace: nowrap;` on the full-width version and then allow it to wrap for each row for less wide screens.

without testing, I think that should make the columns all the same width as the widest content (which can be variable) without specifying what the width is with an absolute value.

I guess it all depends on whether the `li::marker` can be considered its own item in the flexbox flow? I don't know if the browser can be tricked into that if it's not really part of the dom to be manipulated like other things?